# Отсутствует сопоставление типа объекта

Tags: c#

```js
static void OnTimeout(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {


  var alg = new [] {
    ((MyTimer) sender).alg
  };
  var date = new [] {
    ((MyTimer) sender).datetime
  };
  string st = "0";
  //var comment = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).comment.ToString() };
  //var beg = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).Dt_Begin };
  //var end = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).Dt_Period_End };
  //string upd = string.Format("UPDATE ALg_stack SET dt_create=GETDATE() WHERE id=(SELECT id from alg_stack)");


  string sql = string.Format("Insert Into Alg_stack" +
    "(metaAlg,datetime, st, comment, dt_beg, dt_end, dt_create, dt_update) Values( @alg, @date, @st, null, null, null, GETDATE(), null)");

  using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection()) {
    cn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=192.168.1.156;Initial Catalog=ihd_aktobe;User ID=sa;Password=111";

    cn.Open();

    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn)) {


      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alg", alg);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st", st);
      // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", comment);
      // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@begin", beg);
      // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", end);  
      //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@update", upd);


      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    cn.Close();



  }



}
```

Выдает ошибку на `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`:
Additional information: Отсутствует сопоставление типа объекта System.String[] с известным собственным типом управляемого поставщика.

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать и почему пытаетесь массив строк засунуть в одну строку базы данных?

Comment: записывать данные в таблицу

Comment: если сделаю так `var alg =  (MyTimer)sender.alg;
                var date =   (MyTimer)sender.datetime ;` то ошибка  `Error  'object' does not contain a definition for 'alg' and no extension method 'alg' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var alg = ((MyTimer) sender).alg.ToString();
var date =  ((MyTimer) sender).datetime;
```